# trigger to create multiple records based on multiselect picklist value

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on one trigger which is based on Lead object, on lead I have two fields

1) What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c  - Picklist field

2) Other_Programs__c - Multiselect picklist field.

When these two fields are not null then I need to create records in hed__Affiliation__c object.
for picklist fields I am able to achieve creating record in Affiliation object but failed to achieve for multi select picklist field.
If 5 values are selected in multi select picklist field then I need to create 5 records in hed__Affiliation__c object.
Once user select values then I need to match that value names with account names then populate Account__c field on hed__Affiliation__c object with Account Id

Can anyone help me out in this issue please

My code is below:

```
trigger ContactCreationFromLead on Lead (After insert, after update) {
//trigger to create contact, relationship, affiliation records from lead.
List<Contact> conInsertList = new List<Contact>();
List<hed__Affiliation__c> affiliation = new List <hed__Affiliation__c>();
List<hed__Relationship__c> relation = new List<hed__Relationship__c>();
List<String> listEmail = new List<String>();
List<String> listname = new List<String>();
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
for (Lead em : Trigger.new) {
    if(em.Email != null){
        listEmail.add(em.Email);
    }
    if(em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null ){
        listname.add(em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
    }
}
}
//to catch the account Id that matches the lead primary program of interest
//account name should match with primary program of interest picklist values
List<Account> account = [SELECT Id,Name from Account WHERE Name = :listname];
String record;
for(Account acc : account){
    record = acc.Id; 
}

List<Contact> cem = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = :listEmail];
String cemail;
for(Contact ce : cem){
    cemail = ce.Email;
}
//code to create contact for student if form is filled by student
for(Lead ld : Trigger.new) {
    if (ld.Email != cemail && ld.Parent_or_guardian__c == false) {

        Contact cnt = new Contact();

        cnt.FirstName = ld.FirstName;
        cnt.LastName = ld.LastName;
        cnt.Email = ld.Email;
        cnt.RecordTypeId = '012P00000005ZDpIAM';
        conInsertList.add(cnt);
    }
    //code to create contacts for parent and student if form is filled by parent
    else{
        if(ld.Email != cemail && ld.Parent_or_guardian__c == true ){
            Contact cnt1 = new Contact();
            cnt1.RecordTypeId = '012P00000005ZDuIAM';
            cnt1.FirstName = ld.Parent_First_Name__c;
            cnt1.LastName = ld.Parent_Last_Name__c;
            cnt1.Email = ld.Parent_Email__c;
            conInsertList.add(cnt1);
            Contact cnt2 = new Contact();
            cnt2.RecordTypeId = '012P00000005ZDpIAM';
            cnt2.FirstName = ld.FirstName;
            cnt2.LastName = ld.LastName;
            cnt2.Email = ld.Email;
            conInsertList.add(cnt2);
        }
    }
}

if(conInsertList.size()>0){
    INSERT conInsertList;
    List<Id> conInsert = new List<Id>();
    //catch the inserted contact ids to create relationship record
    if(conInsertList.size()>1){
    for(Integer i = 0, s = conInsertList.size(); i < s; i += 2){
        //creates relation record by catching current student and parent record id's
        hed__Relationship__c hedrel = new hed__Relationship__c();
        hedrel.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i + 1].Id;
        hedrel.hed__RelatedContact__c = conInsertList[i].Id;
        hedrel.hed__Type__c = 'Parent';
        relation.add(hedrel);
        //creates affiliation record if filled by parent
        hed__Affiliation__c hedaff = new hed__Affiliation__c();
        hedaff.hed__Account__c = record;
        hedaff.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i + 1].Id;
        hedaff.hed__Primary__c = true;
        affiliation.add(hedaff);

    }
    }
    else{
        //creates Affiliation record if filled by student only
        if(conInsertList.size()==1){
        for(Integer i = 0, s = conInsertList.size(); i < s; i += 2){
        hed__Affiliation__c hedaff = new hed__Affiliation__c();
        hedaff.hed__Account__c = record ;
        hedaff.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i].Id;
        hedaff.hed__Primary__c = true;
        affiliation.add(hedaff);
    }
    }
    }
    insert relation;
    insert affiliation;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any one of the loop that you are iterating on Lead, you can add this logic :

> 1. Get all values in a set from the multiselect field. This will make the values unique.
> 2. Query account object with these names and fetch ids.
> 3. Iterate over account list obtained form above query and create new Affiliation records.

```
Set<String> otherProgramsValueSet = new Set<String>();
for (Lead em : Trigger.new) {
    if(em.Email != null){
        listEmail.add(em.Email);
    }
    if(em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null ){
        listname.add(em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
    }
    if(em.Other_Programs__c != null){
    // this will construct a set of values selected in multiselect. Set will maintain unique values.
    // Multiselect values are semi-colon separated, hence the split function.
        otherProgramsValueSet.addAll(em.Other_Programs__c .split(';')); 
    }
}

//Query account records with matching names.
//Iterate over this list to create new Affiliation records
List<hed__Affiliation__c> affiliationListToBeInserted = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();
for(Account acc : [select id from account where name in : otherProgramsValueSet]){
    affiliationListToBeInserted.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(Account__c= acc.Id));
    //Add more required fields in above statement, if any.
}
insert affiliationListToBeInserted;
```

Comment: Hi Sarang, thanks a lot for your help. I am getting the following error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<String>) from the type Set<String>" at line otherProgramsValueSet.add(em.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';'));  Can you please help me out in this issue here

Comment: Added correction. The method should be `addAll` rather than `add`

Comment: yes, I updated already and it worked, thanks a lot Sarang